# Fastest way to drop multiple rows and columns from SparseArrays

Tags: performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

I would like to prune some unimportant rows and columns from a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) to accelerate solving some eigenvalue problems.

Given

```
sparse =
 KroneckerProduct[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {30, 30}], 
   IdentityMatrix[30, SparseArray]] + 
  KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[30, SparseArray], 
   RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {30, 30}]]
```

I would like to drop a selection of rows and the paired up columns, say `600` of the `900`:

```
toDrop = RandomSample[Range@900, 600];
```

Currently I'm using `Drop` as suggested in the documentation. Unfortunately this will only drop a span of rows and columns at once, so first I have to build an accumulated set of spans, which I've been doing like:

```
dropSpans =
  FoldList[
    {#[[1]] + #2[[2]] - #2[[1]] + 1, #2 - #[[1]]} &,
    {0, None},
    MinMax /@ Split[Sort@toDrop, (#2 - #) == 1 &]
    ][[2 ;;, 2]];
```

Then I have to `Fold` the `Drop` like:

```
Fold[Drop[#, #2, #2] &, sparse, dropSpans];
```

Now this is fine for the 30x30 case:

```
Fold[Drop[#, #2, #2] &, sparse, dropSpans]; // RepeatedTiming // First

0.090
```

But the since matrix size increases as $N^4$ for me here even by the time I'm feed in 120x120 base matrices it takes a full 120 seconds as I'm building a new `SparseArray` object for every step in `Fold`--and the number of steps also increases as $N^2$. If I could just drop all of the parts at once I assume this would be quite fast. I'm also hoping not to have to work with the internal `SparseArray` structure but that's fine if there's no other way.

Comment: I would use `Part` to extract the nondropped rows with the `Complement` of dropped indices as second argument. `Delete` might also work (with the full index set expanded; not with `Spans`). Quite likely, the first is what the latter does internally. So better try both.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher unfortunately `Delete` appears to convert the array to dense array. I had assumed `Part` would be less efficient since in some sense there is more work being done with that, but I suppose the construction overhead of this method will overwhelm that.

Comment: Hm. I cannot confirm that, but anyways, `A[[Complement[Range[Length[A]], idx]]]` seems to be faster (`A` ist the matrix, `idx` the index set of vertices to delete).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher yeah using `Part` for both the rows and the columns simultaneously is actually quite fast. Like .01s to update a 14400x14400 matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is

```
With[{toKeep = Complement[Range[Length[sparse]], toDrop]},
  sparse[[toKeep, toKeep]]
  ];
```

Comment: Works wonderfully.